# Optimization of string to ndarray containing integers and multiple delimiters

Tags: python, numpy, csv, int

I streaming a large amount of ASCII data from a device and decoding it to a string type. The result is a comma and semicolon delimited string.

'-81,-82,-82;-87,-88,-88,-88,'

My objective is to split this string into an ndarray of dimension: [length of semicolons,length of commas]. Each array element is an integer value as seen in my example above. I have implemented two methods to achieve my objective, but they are both very time consuming (around 3-7 seconds). I am working with 10 million integers. Is it possible to reduce the processing time and if so, how should I go about this?

Thanks

```python
#Method 1 (about 3 seconds to process)

BigTrace = BigTraceBytes.decode()
Traces = BigTrace.split(';')

box = np.empty([len(Traces),Record_Length])   
idx= 0

for row in Traces:
   temp = row.split(',')
   box[idx] = [float(i) for i in temp]
   idx+=1

box3d = box.reshape(100,100,1000)

#Method 2 (about 7 seconds to process)

BigTrace = BigTraceBytes.decode()
TraceSplit = (re.split(',|;',BigTrace))
ArrSplit= np.array(TraceSplit)
done = ArrSplit.astype('int')
```

Comment: Hi Max, have you tried passing `int` as the `dtype` arg in [`np.array(TraceSplit, dtype=int)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)? does that save any time?

Comment: also, if you know ahead of time that all of the integers will be between -127 and 128, you can use the `int8` [`dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) which might save a lot of memory?

Comment: also, do you know how long `.decode()` takes? it's in both mehtods, so maybe knowing how long that is may help determine if it's even possible to speed this up more?